# Way to make a WMI call in C# in a service's OnShutdown?

Tags: c#, windows-services, wmi, shutdown

I've a Windows service that I want to record the current network settings to a text file when the computer is shutdown. I'm using WMI calls with the C# `ManagementClass` to do so. However, it is not working.
I believe the problem is because when shutting down, Windows stops the WMI service, then my service tries to make a call using WMI (in its `OnShutdown()`) but can't because the WMI service has already stopped.
Does anybody know of a way around this, or perhaps another way to get the network settings?

Answer (score 2):

You could make your service dependent on the WMI service, which I think will make windows shut yours down before WMI.

To do it from a command line you can use, note the space after the = is important:

```
sc config "MyService" depend= Winmgmt
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work and WMI simply errors with `The RPC server is unavailable.` or something like that..